# Will the CLLocationManager startMonitoringForRegion use the desiredAccuracy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager

I'm initializing my instance of the CLLocationManager  like this:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

....

[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

I've read that the region monitoring is based on WLAN and Cell towers. Furthermore i've read that using a low desiredAccuracy (below 1000) will trigger GPS. However in the documentation the following is stated:

> This property is used only in conjunction with the standard location services and is not used when monitoring significant location changes.

Will startMonitoringForRegion use GPS if i use kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are monitoring the region, desired accuracy has no significance. This is because its not for accurate location based results. They give you the tentative position of the user. Accuracy is applicable when you work with standard services and call the function      `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`. In case of region monitoring and significant location changes, accuracy is ignored.

Comment: If i have two instances of locationManager and one uses startUpDatingLocation and the other uses region monitoring. Will setting the desiredAccuracy on one instance influence the other?

Comment: There is no passive location services in iOS like android. So, it will not influence other.